# switch to semantic version on app store and play store

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, app-store, versioning

I am developping an app with Ionic (Cordova) but not using a semantic format for my versions.

in my config file, the version tag number is 1.69 for Android and 138 for iOS.

Is there a way to switch to semantic format and if so, which number should I use next ?

By the way, would it be possible to use the same version number for both the stores, without getting an error regarding precedence?

Thanks

config.xml for iOS:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <widget android-versionCode="1700" id="com.board" ios-CFBundleVersion="1700" ios-CFBundleVersionString="139" version="139" versionCode="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   <name>Board</name>
   <description>
    ...
```

config.xml for Android:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <widget android-versionCode="1700" id="com.board" ios-CFBundleVersion="1700" ios-CFBundleVersionString="139" version="1.7.0" versionCode="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   <name>Board</name>
   <description>
    ...
```

Comment: have you 2 identical configs for both platforms? PS: You wrote config.xml for iOS on both the snippets

Comment: sorry, no. I made a mitake, i fixed it. The "version" is different

Answer (score 0):

The app version on Android it's simply a string.
You have 2 values, versionCode(int) and versionName(string). With every update of your application you need to increase the versionCode number but you can use the same versionName because they are indipendent from each other.

In iOS you have bundle number and bundle string short which are pretty the same thing.

To follow a common versioning pattern http://semver.org/ you could go with: 1.7.0 with your next release in both the stores.

For more information about versioning, check those links:

**iOS**
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016603-CH1-WHERE_THESE_NUMBERS_APPEAR_IN_XCODE_AND_IN_YOUR_APP-IN_EACH_XCODE_TARGET_S_GENERAL_TAB

**Android**
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: thanks Mat, but what is the "version" tag in my config.xml file then ?
And will 1.7.0 be higher thatn my current ios version 138 ?

Comment: @Louis i honestly never used Cordova for building apps, but from what i've found in this document: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html seems that version field is the "publicily available string which the user will see in the store" and in which you need to put the string "1.7.0". Then in Android one you need to put android-versionCode="actualNumber + 1" and in iOS one ios-CFBundleVersion="actualNumber + 1"

Comment: @Louis Here you can get more info about how Android version is builded by the framework in Android: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-the-version-code, and based on this overall infos i will go for using version: "1.7.0" and let the system build the appropriate versionCode for Android and BundleVersion for iOS without specifing them in the configs. Let me know if it works ;)

Comment: do you think going from 138 to 1.7.0 on iTunesConnect won't popup a precedence error ?

Comment: @Louis i suggest you to try, if the system doesn't admit the new version it will block you before you can publish the app. PlayStore has the same versionCode checking when you upload a new APK and prevent regressions

Comment: didn't work for iOS, my previous version was 138, so as it's bigger than 1.7.0, they didn't accept it, I had to pu 139.  any solution to go back to semantic on the App Store ?

Comment: @Louis can you share the code of your config.xml (of both platforms)? Strip away all the unnecessary part from them.